# Warning when i am installing ADT plug in to eclipse 3.5.2

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Warning : Your installing software that contains unsigned content. The authenticity and validity of this software can't be established.Do you want to continue with the installation..

I tried the by downloading ADT plug in as zip file even i am getting same error.

How can i solve this issue..

I installed eclipse 3.5.2 j2ee version

Comment: What does this have to do with Cocoa? Retagged.

Answer (score 0):

Weird I'd say this is normal. It even asks you if you want to continue right? Can't you just click on yes or continue? I always get this "error" as you call it when I am installing the ADT plugin. But for me it is just a warning and there is some button to just continue. It would be very weird if you can't.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a warning, not an error. It just says that eclipse.org can't validate the software you're installing.

Answer (score 0):

There's also a button or checkbox to remember your selection so you don't have to cycle through the same prompts all the time.  I noticed this with Windows 7 and considered it a safety feature, even letting me only run this type of stuff when I'm on a secured or home network...

Answer (score 0):

Run as Administrator mode.
you should open the Eclipse in Admin Mode, so after this warning it will continue to install